# Align text verically in center with respect to icon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have div with text and icon. On large screens text is not vertically centered. Here is the bootply link: http://www.bootply.com/CHKeRxKOX6

[image]

How should I write this to be looks good on every size of screen?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to you css:

```
.panel-body .col-md-10 {
    display: table;
    height: 80px;
}
.panel-body .col-md-10 > h4 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div class="emr-alert panel panel-default col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3" align="center">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-9">
        <h4>
          Your program has not been integrated with your EMR system.
          Please contact your administrator for more information regarding system integration.
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```